# Android- Gyro Sensor

Tags: tracking, accelerometer

I am using LG Optimus 2x smartphone which consists of  gyro and accelrometer sensors. I am using it in indoor tracking application by using pedestrian dead reckoning techniques. I want to use gyro sensor to get correct orientation of mobile. I am integrating gyro data over time to get angles. But these angles are not well accurate. how I  can get error free angles from Gyro sensor.

navig

Answer (score 0):

I am using the method described in this [manuscript](http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf) and it works like charm in my application. It gives very accurate orientations.

I am curious. What method do you use for tracking the pedestrian? How do you use orientation?

The best pedometer algorithm I have found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375381/are-there-any-well-known-algorithms-to-count-steps-based-on-accelerometery/6375802#6375802). It seems to me you have something better. Could you share it?